# Multi-line python comment search and replace

Tags: search

I have a python code with several multi-line comments like this:

```
def hello:
    ''' some comment
        some more text
        some mooore text
    '''

def ciaoo:
    ''' some comment
        some more text
        some mooore text
    '''
```

These exist throughout the file. I need to get rid of them.

I tried something like: `:%s/'''.*'''//g` and `%s/'''\(\_.*\)'''//g`. But turns out I really suck at regex.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `%s/\s*\('''\)\_.\{-}\1\n//` ?

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Do you mind writing this as an answer so that I can mark it answered? (and also possibly explain it, if it's fine, as I still don't understand how it worked while mine didn't :D )

Comment: @Ixvs was faster than me but their answer is good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation for `%s/\s*\('''\)\_.\{-}\1\n//` in the comment:

- `\s*\('''\)` means some or none white spaces and following `'''`.
- `\_.` matches any character, including new lines.
- `\{-}` in Vim is equivalent to `*?` in regex, which means none or some, but as short as possible. E.g. for `book`, `bo*` matches `boo`, but `bo*?` matches `b` (none of `o` was matched), while both `bo*k` and `bo*?k` matches `book`.

  - BTW, in Vim, `\{}` = `*`,
- `\1` refers to first parenthesized expression, i.e. `'''` in this case.
- `\n` means a new line after second `'''`.

Comment: Activating the very magic mode can certainly make this easier on the eyes `%s/\v\s*(''')\_.{-}\1\n//`